# Drush 5.9 - unable to untar

Tags: drush

Using the command:

```
 drush arr ~/drush-backups/site.tar.gz --db-url=mysql://df_database:password@localhost/df_databaseuser --destination=~/domains/site.kz/public_html/temp
```

(archive size is ~5gb),

I get this error:

```
 Unable to untar /home/user/drush-backups/site.tar.gz.                [error]
 Unable to extract site archive tarball to                            [error]
 /tmp/drush_tmp_1384866055_528b6107d88d6.
```

Why does it happen? However, when I try to untar archive lower than 1gb I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: and what's in your OS error log?

Comment: If you can't untar any file larger than 1gb you have a problem with your OS. Can you confirm that this is definitely a Drupal issue by trying that?

Comment: Just tried ~3gb archive. Worked well either. Is there a chance its a problem with a drush config?

Comment: Try extracting it using `tar -xzvf site.tar.gz` to determine if it's your OS or Drush/Drupal causing the problem

Comment: tar xvfz - worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

By default the command **drush archive-restore** creates a unique temporary folder under **/tmp** (*/tmp/drush_tmp_1394487346_531e303223...*) where it will extract the archived tarball content, and later will move the $doc_root into the $destination - with the option **overwrite**.

I guess your **/tmp** folder resides on a separate partition, ~4GB in size; restoring a 3GB archive worked well, but it fails for 5BG. It looks like **drush archive-restore** works only when the system's temp folder is large enough to accommodate the extracted tarball.

PS. **drush archive-restore** is defined in `archive.drush.inc` :

```
function "drush_archive_restore" (drush_tarball_extract($file, $tmp)), where $tmp = drush_tempdir();
```

`Funtion drush_tempdir()` is defined in filesystem.inc - creates a unique temporary directory  and returns its path. `drush_tempdir()` uses `drush_find_tmp()` which more likely returns `/tmp`

Answer (score 0):

I got this **exact** error when I tried the following from a script:

```
drush arr ${DUMP_DIR}/`ls ./ | grep *.tar.gz` --destination=/home/foo/bar
```

with a single .tar.gz file in the directory. It turns out my filename was like: `some-file-MM-DD-YY-HH:MM:SS.tar.gz

in this case the `:` (colons) are not escaped by my shellscript and I get that generic extract error. Renaming my dump file to something simple like `dump.tar.gz` allows the drush command to complete.