# Drush 7 downloads modules in zip format

Tags: 7, drush

I had Drush 6 working correctly. I had been using Drush 7 on Mac working correctly but now I installed Drush 7 on Windows. Now when I download modules using drush like `drush dl Panels`, it downloads the module in a zip format shows the message "Project Panels contains 0 modules." and hence I can't enable them until I unzip them manually.

Comment: Maybe it's just some temporary network glitch. Try again with `-vd` parameter and paste further info if you can reproduce it.

Comment: Thank you @kenorb for your comment. The network is fine. I have tried it on different times. The command shows different details. It does download the module but in zip format and it also shows this message "Unable to untar C:\Users\adam\AppData\Local\Temp\drush_tmp_1428794692\cto4716.tmp"

Comment: Also make sure you've `tar` and `unzip` commands available (in your `PATH`) as `drush` depends on them. Also make sure you've write access to `Temp` folder (on Windows probably you've).

Comment: Similar: [Drush 5.9 - unable to untar](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/94701/1908), [Drush up error - unable to untar - Destination already exists](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/108472/1908)